# What is the original ancient Egyptian names for the "Book of Two Ways"?

Tags: egyptian, afterlife

After much research, I am asking for help with this matter. I can find no reverse translation for the "Book of Two Ways." Is it like the "Book of the Dead," a modern convenience name for this set of texts, when its original name wasn't discovered until more recently (rw nw prt m hrw 'Utterances of Coming Forth in the Day’) ? Or is there no known name for it? I have read that it is also called the “Guide to the Ways of Rostau”. If anyone knows the original Egyptian name for either of these two naming conceits and could share them, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

​Hi,

Most likely, you would probably need an interlinear bilingual translation with phonetization of the hieroglyphs. As far as I'm concerned, no such edition exists.

Perhaps the late **Theban** version "**Pert em hru**" will serve the purpose? I know it's Budge, and a lot of research was carried out since then, but why not? I guess it should be called "The book of life for the dead to have a safe journey", very much like Orphic Golden Tablets.

Budge E. A. Wallis. 198AD. The Book of the Dead : The Papyrus of Ani in the British Museum : The Egyptian Text with Interlinear Transliteration and Translation a Running Translation Introduction Etc Dover ed. Gloucester MA: Peter Smith. , p. XXX, accessible here:

[Internet Archives](https://archive.org/details/egyptianbookofde00erne_0/page/n31/mode/2up)

[image: 2]